# Does Growl keep a history?

Tags: snow-leopard, growl

Does **Growl**, either natively or with an extension, keep a history, possibly accessible through a graphic interface?

(something like **Jumpcut**, I mean)

I'm talking about OSX 10.6 (hence Growl 1.2.2), I dunno if the Lion version is different.

Comment: Which Growl version though?

Comment: @Gerry 1.2.2, as it is the last version available for Snow Leopard. Accepted your answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware the MAS version is not supported under Snow Leopard, but indeed it seems to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Growl 1.3 (available on the Mac App Store) supports a history of notifications, and additionally a rollup of all notifications while you are away from the computer. Unfortunately it requires Mac OS X Lion. You can get to the history right from the Growl Preferences.

Earlier versions did not have this feature.